# Possible range of angle a

Tags: geometry

A line makes an angle a with both x and y axes. Then find the possible range of a.
           I don't know whether this problem is a misprint. So, if you think this problem is a printing mistake of the book, please inform and I will remove the question. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any reason to think it is a misprint. In 2D, the range is degenerate (as only $a = 45°$ satisfies the condition), but in 3D there really is a range of angles for $a$.

Comment: But this is a 2D problem and they had not asked for a value, they had asked for a range

Comment: Well, the range, or more properly, [interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) $a = [ 45°, 45° ]$ is a valid interval; just a degenerate one (since it contains only one exact value), and not a proper one (with infinitely many real elements in it). It is still a very valid problem, because you do need to show exactly why this is so. (In other words, *finding* the answer is not the real task here; showing the logic/proof of it is, I believe.)

Comment: For example, I would start by showing a simple illustration, with the two angles marked $\theta$ and $\varphi$. Then, I would show that regardless of the orientation of the line, in two dimensions we always have $\theta + \varphi = 90°$. (Note: This is not true in 3D, but if you work out the inequality in 3D, you find the answer the same way.) Since the requirement is that $a = \theta = \varphi$, the only possible solution is $a + a = 90°$, i.e. $a = 45°$. While this is a single value, it is still a range; a range with exactly one real in it: $45° \le a \le 45°$, or $[ 45°, 45°]$.

Comment: But the book has given a different answer. It's answer is [45, 90], i couldn't show the degree signs

Comment: That is the correct answer for 3D. You said the problem was supposed to be in 2D; did the book/problem explicitly say this, or did you infer it some other way? (In three dimensions, we have $90° \le \theta + \varphi \le 180°$, and therefore $90° \le a + a \le 180° \iff 45° \le a \le 90°$. The lower limit applies when the line is in the $xy$ plane, and the latter limit when the line is parallel to the $z$ axis.)

Comment: I think that may be my mistake.Should I remove this question?

Comment: I don't know. My **opinion** is that you should write an answer, saying that you assumed (incorrectly; perhaps mention why?) that the question is in 2D, while the correct answer given is definitely for 3D; the 3D problem being interesting and non-tricky, not-very-hard.  (The basis for my opinion is that it would be most helpful for others searching for answers to a similar question.)